# meteor react-autosuggest - Missing class properties transform

Tags: meteor, reactjs, autosuggest

I'm using Meteor React and trying to get react-autosuggest working (from the basic usage example https://github.com/moroshko/react-autosuggest

The error I get is `Missing class properties transform` - it's happening at onChange (right after this.state.

```js
this.state = {
      value: '',
      suggestions: getSuggestions('')
    };
  }

  onChange = (event, { newValue }) => {
    this.setState({
      value: newValue
    });
  };

  onSuggestionsUpdateRequested = ({ value }) => {
    this.setState({
      suggestions: getSuggestions(value)
    });
  };
```

I've looked around to see if I could find a solution, but no luck.

Hopefully someone can shed some light on what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Using `class Example extends React.Component {...}` doesn't work with meteor. Try this approach instead:

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import Autosuggest from 'react-autosuggest';
import AutosuggestHighlight from 'autosuggest-highlight';

Example = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      value: '',
      suggestions: [],
    };
  },

  onChange(event, { newValue }) {
    this.setState({
      value: newValue,
    });
  },

  onSuggestionsFetchRequested({ value }) {
    this.setState({
      suggestions: this.getSuggestions(value),
    });
  },

  onSuggestionsClearRequested() {
    this.setState({
      suggestions: [],
    });
  },

  getSuggestionValue(suggestion) {
    return suggestion.name;
  },

  getSuggestions(value) {
    const languages = [
      {
        name: 'C',
        year: 1973,
      },
      {
        name: 'C#',
        year: 2001,
      },
      {
        name: 'C++',
        year: 1984,
      },
      {
        name: 'Clojure',
        year: 2008,
      },
      {
        name: 'Elm',
        year: 2013,
      },
      {
        name: 'Go',
        year: 2010,
      },
    ];
    const inputValue = value.trim().toLowerCase();
    const inputLength = inputValue.length;

    if (inputLength === 0) {
      return [];
    }

    return languages.filter(language =>
      language.name.toLowerCase().slice(0, inputLength) === inputValue
    );
  },

  renderSuggestion(suggestion, { query }) {
    const suggestionText = `${suggestion.name} (${suggestion.year})`;
    const matches = AutosuggestHighlight.match(suggestionText, query);
    const parts = AutosuggestHighlight.parse(suggestionText, matches);

    return (
      <span className="suggestion-content">
        <span>
          {
            parts.map((part, index) => {
              const className = part.highlight ? 'highlight' : null;

              return (
                <span className={className} key={index}>{part.text}</span>
              );
            })
          }
        </span>
      </span>
    );
  },

  render() {
    const { value, suggestions } = this.state;
    const inputProps = {
      value,
      placeholder: 'Enter programming language...',
      onChange: this.onChange,
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <Autosuggest
          suggestions={suggestions}
          onSuggestionsFetchRequested={this.onSuggestionsFetchRequested}
          onSuggestionsClearRequested={this.onSuggestionsClearRequested}
          getSuggestionValue={this.getSuggestionValue}
          renderSuggestion={this.renderSuggestion}
          inputProps={inputProps} />
      </div>
    );
  },
});
```

Then simply use `<Example />` to render the autosuggest field.

This was tested with Meteor 1.4.1.1